# Using gulp-modernizr how to set the config file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, modernizr

I am using gulp-modernizr and I have read how to set destination folder, file name and many options (everything explained in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-modernizr))

But I don't know how to set configuration file, I have tried setting the src but it doesn't work:

```
gulp.task('modernizr', function() {
gulp.src("./node_modules/modernizr/lib/config-all.json") 
    .pipe(modernizr('outputFileName.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('node_modules/modernizr/')) // destination folder
});
```

I know how to do it from command line:

```
modernizr -c ./lib/config-all.json
```

**But could anybody explain how to set the configuration file location using gulp-modernizr?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't pass the location of your config file to `gulp-modernizr`. Instead you pass the settings themselves as an object:

```
gulp.task('modernizr', function() {
  var settings = { 
    "options" : [
      "setClasses",
      "addTest",
      "html5printshiv",
      "testProp",
      "fnBind"
    ]
  };
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(modernizr('outputFileName.js', settings))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('node_modules/modernizr/')) // destination folder
});
```

If you have a JSON config file that you want to use you can read that file using `require()` and pass the resulting object to `modernizr()`:

```
gulp.task('modernizr', function() {
  var settings = require('./node_modules/modernizr/lib/config-all.json');
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(modernizr('outputFileName.js', settings))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('node_modules/modernizr/')) // destination folder
});
```

Comment: Do you know why this gulp package is using gulp.src('./js/*.js')? Doesn't seem to make any sense

Comment: It runs [`customizr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/customizr) on those files, which finds all uses of `Modernizr` and creates a custom `modernizr` distribution that includes only the used features.